# Smooth Transition Between Background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I made this script where the background changes the farther you scroll down the page, but I want it so there is a transition between each of the images. So when you scroll from one image to the next, it slowly fades into the next. Sort of like a parallax.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body ").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/rs2Ittp.jpg')");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
     $("body ").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/rs2Ittp.jpg')");
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
      $("body ").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/H5QLuD6.jpg')");
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 2000) {
      $("body ").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/KzZpgdS.jpg')");
    }
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 3000) {
     $("body ").css("background-image", "url('http://i.imgur.com/UsLLJSx.jpg')");
    }
  });
});
```

Any solutions are appreciated (:

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is through CSS:

```
body {
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Edit: My answer may have been a bit premature, since this is not a cross-browser solution. A better way to do this would be by using two divs with different background images using `transition: opacity 0.5s;` A lot more javascript is involved in this solution though.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, by adding and removing classes on the elements at certain scroll points. You could overcome the cross-browser problem easily by using an autoprefixer together with sass, less or my favorite, stylus. codepen can do it for you

Answer (score 0):

[Here's one way of doing it.](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/WvrOqV?editors=011)
Create two elements with `position: fixed`, then change the opacity as you scroll. Once you get over a certain scroll position, swap the next images in and use the same opacity logic minus the intended scroll length.

edit: my opacity math could be more refined + need to add swapping the images back when scrolling the reverse direction

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="top"></div>
```

```
/* css */
.bottom,
.top {
  position: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
// js
var img1 = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/rs2Ittp.jpg)'
  , img2 = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/H5QLuD6.jpg)'
  , img3 = 'url(http://i.imgur.com/KzZpgdS.jpg)'

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.top').css("background-image", img1)
  $('.bottom').css("background-image", img2)

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop()

    if (scrollTop < 1000) {
      $('.top').css('opacity', 100 / scrollTop)
    }

    else if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
      $('.top').css("background-image", img2)
      $('.bottom').css("background-image", img3)
      $('.top').css('opacity', 100 / (scrollTop - 1000))
    }
  })
})
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/WvrOqV)**

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! But it won't work when I have content. Where do I put in the site content? Between the top and bottom divs?